# Клиент-серверное приложение не работает

Tags: c++, клиент-сервер

Написал две программы: клиент и сервер. На моем компе все работает отлично. При запуске, сервер ничего не должен писать, а при подключении он напишет "Client connected". При запуске клиента, он через короткие промежутки времени должен писать "Error failed connect to server!", а если подключение прошло, то должны отобразиться: "Connected" и "Hello, world!"  Ну, а если скидываю знакомому, то, во-первых, подключение не происходит, во-вторых, клиент редко "пытается" подключиться. Что можно исправить?
Код сервера:

```
#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

#pragma warning(disable: 4996)

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    WSAData wsaData;
    WORD DLLVersion = MAKEWORD(2, 1);
    if (WSAStartup(DLLVersion, &wsaData) != 0) {
        std::cout << "Error" << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    SOCKADDR_IN addr;
    int sizeofaddr = sizeof(addr);
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("***.***.*.***"); //тут вводится ip
    addr.sin_port = htons(1111);
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;

    SOCKET sListen = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, NULL);
    bind(sListen, (SOCKADDR*)&addr, sizeof(addr));
    listen(sListen, SOMAXCONN);


    SOCKET newConnection;
    newConnection = accept(sListen, (SOCKADDR*)&addr, &sizeofaddr);

    if (newConnection == 0) {
        std::cout << "Error №2\n";
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "Client Connected!\n";
        char msg[256] = "Hello, world!";
        send(newConnection, msg, sizeof(msg), NULL);
    }


    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Код клиента:

```
#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

#pragma warning(disable: 4996)

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    WSAData wsaData;
    WORD DLLVersion = MAKEWORD(2, 1);
    if (WSAStartup(DLLVersion, &wsaData) != 0) {
        std::cout << "Error" << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    SOCKADDR_IN addr;
    int sizeofaddr = sizeof(addr);
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("***.***.*.***"); //тут вводится ip
    addr.sin_port = htons(1111);
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    while (true) {
        SOCKET Connection = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, NULL);
        if (connect(Connection, (SOCKADDR*)&addr, sizeof(addr)) != 0) {
            std::cout << "Error failed connect to server!\n";
            //return 1;
        }
        else {
            std::cout << "Connected!\n";
            char msg[256];
            recv(Connection, msg, sizeof(msg), NULL);
            std::cout << msg << std::endl;
        }
    }


    system("pause");
    return 0;
```

Comment: неинициализированные структуры, отсутствие проверок результатов функций, утечка практически всех ресурсов

Comment: надо дать разрешения на работу с сетью в брэндмауэре виндовс